# How to check if you have live internet connection programmatically using C++

Tags: c++, connection

How can I check if I have a internet connection or live internet connection using C++?

Comment: Do you really need an "internet" connection? As opposed to being connected to servers X, Y and Z you need to communicate with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ has no builtin functions for this, you will need to resort to system APIs. An easiest and obvious way is to create a socket and try to connect it to some known IP or check if DNS is working.

Some useful links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673(VS.85).aspx (Windows Sockets)
http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html (Linux/Unix sockets)

Comment: I will check the windows system api. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to try to connect to a known outside IP address.  If it fails in Windows, the connect function will return SOCKET_ERROR, and WSAGetLastError will usually return WSAEHOSTUNREACH (meaning the packet couldn't be sent to the host).  In Linux, you'll get back a -1, and errno will be ENETUNREACH.

Answer (score -1):

For starters you can subscribe to the `ISensIntf` to check if you have a valid network connection. (Let me know if you need help in this. Its painful to register for the events etc.). 
After that, you can use Api's like `IsNetworkAlive`, `InternetGetConnectedStateEx` or the `InternetCheckConnection` to check connectivity to the internet etc.

If your using C# or VB, then first Add a reference to

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Code.
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network network = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network();
                network.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.NetworkAvailableEventHandler(network_NetworkAvailabilityChanged);

...

private static void network_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.NetworkAvailableEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsNetworkAvailable)
            {
                 //network is connected.. do something..
            }
            else
            {
                //network isnt connected.. do something else.
            }
```

Hope this helps